# iOS Text Navigation Bar

Tags: ios, text, navigation

I want to build a navigation bar in iOS 5 with text only items.
How to build this kind of navigation bar?

I don't khow what I need: a scrollview (horizontal) with... Is it possible to do that with the Tab Bar Controller?

Thanks.

Check this snapshot: http://www.eazyrf.com/Snap2.jpg

Comment: This isn't a "navigation bar", or a "tab bar". It's probably some sort of `UITableView` subclass, or at least a `UIScrollView` subclass.

Answer (score 0):

A quick search on google returned a couple of results:

- [UIScrollView Menu bar](http://maniacdev.com/2010/06/creating-custom-uiscrollview-menu-bars-on-the-ipad/) - You've got the right idea with the
  `UIScrollView`, this will point you in the right direction.
- [UITabBarController Menu bar](http://kurrytran.blogspot.com/2011/10/ios-5-tutorial-creating-custom-tab-bar.html) - Here is another example of how you
  can make a custom `UITabBarController`

These should be a good place to start. Good luck!